# Logic: Conditional Proof

Tags: logic, proof-writing

$(G\land H)\to (J\equiv L)$

$(G\equiv H)$

$(H\land\neg L)\lor(H\land K)$    |   $J\to K$

I am trying to use a conditional proof to solve this one. So I'm assuming J is true and using that to prove K. Any help on how to proceed from there is appreciated.

Comment: What is your question Jerry?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I know I can solve this using a conditional proof, so I am trying to assume J and using that to prove K. But once I do that, I'm unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's be generous and give some hints!

a) From the third premiss you can deduce $H$  (each disjunct implies $H$: you'll need to use $\lor$-elimination).

b) Now you can trivially use the second premiss to get $G$ as well.

c) You can easily see how to get from what you've now proved -- using your supposition $J$ and another premiss -- to $L$!

d) You'll now need to use $L$ and the third premiss again to get $H \land K$ -- can you see how to do that?

e) So now you can surely wrap things up into a nicely formatted proof according to the rules of whatever natural deduction proof-system you are using!

Comment: Thanks so much, Peter! This is exactly what I needed to get going on this proof. Usually I'm pretty good at these, but this one has been tripping me up for awhile. I really appreciate your hints and help!